# How to transform a shapefile with a MN03 (LV03) coordinate system into a shapefile with a MN95 (LV95) coordinate system?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, affine-transformation, switzerland

Switzerland is currently introducing new coordinates: by the end of 2016, all federal and cantonal reference data (e.g. the Swiss cadastral system) sould be transformed to the new highly-accurate LV95 reference frame, and all other basic geodata are to follow by 2020.

How can we transform a coordinate system of a shapefile to this new coordinate system (MN95 or LV95) in order to "read" it over datas in this new coordinate system (MN95 or LV95)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to display an existing layer, you can do the following, assuming that your project's CRS is CH1903+ (ESPG 2056) and that you enabled on the fly projection* :

- Open the layer in Qgis
- Right click its name in the list, "set CRS"-> "set layer CRS"
- In the list, select the older CHS (CH1903, ESPG 21781 )
- The layers should then display correctly.

If the CRS was properly set, you should have nothing to do, Qgis should automatically recognise the different CRS and reproject accordingly.

If you also want to create a new layer in the right CRS, all you have to do is, assuming the layer displays properly at the right position :

- Right click its name in the list, "Export"-> "save features as"
- 4th line, select the new CRS (ESPG 2056)
- Save it as a new layer

.* Might be enabled by default in Qgis 3.* ?

Comment: It worked for the option "create a new layer", I had to put this option : "Yes" at the question "RESIZE". If you let "No" it does not work.

Comment: I'm not absolutely sure, but the QGIS transformation only add a "1 and 2 before coordinates. It's Ok if you don't need a good precision. Swisstopo have a tool for "real" transformation : https://www.swisstopo.admin.ch/de/karten-daten-online/calculation-services/reframe.html  @VirginieFavre. I never had problem with the "RESIZE" option?

Comment: @ VirginieFavre I've never seen the resize option either. Which data format are you working with? 
@Christophe that is something I was also wondering. I think I read somewhere that the differences could reach 1m or more in some places away from the center (like Geneva), but I've never seen any offset converting those data.

Comment: @Kantan  https://www.swisstopo.admin.ch/fr/connaissances-faits/mensuration-geodesie/nouvelles-coordonnees/changement-cadre/informations-generales.html

Comment: I've been told by the Vaud administration that REFRAME does not work...indeed as I could try.

Comment: REFRAME is the tool of Swisstopo

Comment: @Kantan : EPSG 2056